# как с помощью js убирать - добавлять css свойство элементу?

Tags: javascript, css

на странице существует элемент

```
var viewh2 = $(".block_peptides:last-child .block-item .title_view h2")
```

у него есть `margin-bottom=10px`

необходимо при клике открывать список и делать `margin-bottom = 40px`

при повторном клике - список закрывается и нужно чтобы `margin-bottom` обратно делался 10px

сначала я сделал так:

```
 `  $(".title_view h2").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".block_content").slideToggle(300);
    viewh2.css("margin-bottom", "40px");
    return false;
    });`
```

список открывается марджин = 40px
Но закрывается и марджин остается 40px
Хотел решить проблему вот так:

```
    if ($(".block_content").is(":hidden")){
    viewh2.css("margin-bottom", "10px");
}else if ($(".block_content").is(":visible")) {
    viewh2.css("margin-bottom", "40px");
}
```

не помогает...
Подскажите как правильно надо делатть?

Answer (score 0):

В css создать два класса:

```
.active {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.hidden {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

В html присвоить класс `hidden` и в js переключать классы. Этот код надо вставить в onclick обработчик:

```
viewh2.toggleClass('active');
viewh2.toggleClass('hidden');
```

Comment: `viewh2.toggleClass('active hidden');`

Comment: Вынужден не согласиться ведь в какой то момент оба класса будут деактивированны

Comment: Eliot Alderson, да спасибо так работает, хотя интерес не пропал как же на чистом js правильно делать)